# ways for a client to identify the specific access point it is connected to within a single SSID?

Tags: android, wifi, uniqueidentifier, access-point

The problem is as follows - there's a university campus wide wifi connection with a single SSID, say "campus-wifi".  The user freely roams around campus, and the usual hand-off between access points occurs.  My question is, is there any information at any layer of the network stack that allows the *client* to identify (any unique identifier is fine) the specific access point they're connected to, rather than simply the fact that they are connected to "campus-wifi"?

If it's relevant, I'd like to be able to do this from mobile devices (android/iOS primarily).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the BSSID of the access point you are connected to. Something like:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
String BSSID = info.getBSSID();
```

Not 100% what you'll get back with the BSSID since I've never used it -- but it should uniquely ID the base station -- Wikipedia seems to indicate that you'll get the MAC of the AP (near the bottom):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Basic_service_set_identifier_.28BSSID.29

-- Dan

---

EDIT:

According to the Android docs, it is the MAC address:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Comment: Don't forget to add the permission for ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your Android Manifest.